# Best way to calculate human readable elapsed time

Tags: php, algorithm, elapsedtime

I am wondering what is the most elegant way of calculating a human readable elasped time given a certain amount of seconds. I want to write this in PHP.

Here is the output needed:

- elapsedTimeInSeconds > one year, output "# years, # months"
- elapsedTimeInSeconds > one month, output "# months, # days"
- elapsedTimeInSeconds > one day, output "# days, # hours"
- elapsedTimeInSeconds > one hour, output "# hours, # minutes"
- elapsedTimeInSeconds > one minute, output "# minutes, # seconds"

I have tried different solutions that are awkward and full of conditional statements, but I was hoping for a more recursive and "clean code" method.

Comment: Six conditional statements aren't too bad, although I WOULD put it into a function at the very least (code reuse and all that jazz). I'm not sure if this is a good recursive problem though, since there is no base case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
function durationFormat($time)
{
    if(gmdate("Y", $time)>1970) return (1970-gmdate("Y",$time)).gmdate(" \y\r\s ", $time).(gmdate("n",$time)-1).gmdate(" \m\o\n\t\h\s ", $time).(gmdate("j",$time)-1).gmdate(" \d\a\y\s H:i:s", $time);
    if(gmdate("n", $time)>1) return (gmdate("n",$time)-1).gmdate(" \m\o\n\t\h\s ", $time).(gmdate("j",$time)-1).gmdate(" \d\a\y\s H:i:s", $time);
    if(gmdate("j", $time)>1) return (gmdate("j",$time)-1).gmdate(" \d\a\y\s H:i:s", $time);
    return gmdate("H:i:s", $time);
}
```

It's a bit quick and dirty but does the job

OR

```
function durationFormat2($seconds)
{
    $a_sec=1;
    $a_min=$a_sec*60;
    $an_hour=$a_min*60;
    $a_day=$an_hour*24;
    $a_week=$a_day*52;
    //$a_month=$a_day*(floor(365/12));
    $a_month=$a_day*30;
    $a_year=$a_day*365;

    $params=2;
    $text='';
    if($seconds>$a_year)
    {
        $years=floor($seconds/$a_year);
        $text.=$years.' years ';
        $seconds=$seconds-($years*$a_year);
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    if($seconds>$a_month)
    {
        $months=floor($seconds/$a_month);
        $text.=$months.' months ';
        $seconds=$seconds-($months*$a_month);
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    if($seconds>$a_week)
    {
        $weeks=floor($seconds/$a_week);
        $text.=$weeks.' weeks ';
        $seconds=$seconds-($months*$a_week);
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    if($seconds>$a_day)
    {
        $days=floor($seconds/$a_day);
        $text.=$days.' days ';
        $seconds=$seconds-($days*$a_day);
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    $H=gmdate("H", $seconds);
    if($H>0)
    {
        $text.=$H.' hours ';
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    $M=gmdate("i", $seconds);
    if($M>0)
    {
        $text.=$M.' minutes ';
        $params--;
    }
    if($params==0) return $text;
    $S=gmdate("s", $seconds);
    $text.=$S.' seconds ';

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: +1 with the edit; the requirements do say, though, that the text has only two parts. Perhaps in the if-statements, push them to a queue, and at the end of the function, pop the first two off and go from there?

Comment: altered to allow only 2 elements

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more flexible, as you can easily add new units like decade, century, etc, and the code wouldn't change:

```
$names = array("seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "months", "years");
$values = array(1, 60, 3600, 24 * 3600, 30 * 24 * 3600, 365 * 24 * 3600);

$time = ...elapsedTimeInSeconds...;
for($i = count($values) - 1; $i > 0 && $time < $values[$i]; $i--);
if($i == 0) {
    echo intval($time / $values[$i]) . " " . $names[$i];
} else {
    $t1 = intval($time / $values[$i]);
    $t2 = intval(($time - $t1 * $values[$i]) / $values[$i - 1]);
    echo "$t1 " . $names[$i] . ", $t2 " . $names[$i - 1];
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I wil try this one ASAP.

Comment: @cellover, how quick is your ASAP? :)

Comment: ASAP usually stands for "several years to a century".
I tried it but finally decided to go for a more readable solution as I mentionned in that reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548792/best-way-to-calculate-human-readable-elapsed-time/15551814#15551814

Comment: A year is not 365 days. It is either 365 days or 366 days, depending on whether it was a leap year.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your suggestions.

I mainly used Waygood and ChrisForrence's suggestions for this method. I tried to keep it as simple as possible and introduced simple arguments such as detail level and delimiter (for string ouput).

```
public function elapsedTimeHumanReadable($date = null, $detailLevel = 2, $delimiter = ' et ')
{
    if($date === null)
    {
        $date = self::now();
    }

    $sec = $this->elapsedSecond($date);

    $a_sec = 1;
    $a_min = $a_sec * 60;
    $an_hour = $a_min * 60;
    $a_day = $an_hour * 24;
    $a_month = $a_day * 30;
    $a_year = $a_day * 365;

    $text = '';
    $resultStack = array();
    if($sec >= $a_year)
    {
        $years = floor($sec / $a_year);
        $text .= $years . $this->plural($years, ' an');
        $sec = $sec - ($years * $a_year);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    if($sec >= $a_month)
    {
        $months = floor($sec / $a_month);
        $text = $months . ' mois';
        $sec = $sec - ($months * $a_month);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    if($sec >= $a_day)
    {
        $days = floor($sec / $a_day);
        $text = $days . $this->plural($days, ' jour');
        $sec = $sec - ($days * $a_day);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    if($sec >= $an_hour)
    {
        $hours = floor($sec / $an_hour);
        $text = $hours . $this->plural($hours, ' heure');
        $sec = $sec - ($hours * $an_hour);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    if($sec >= $a_min)
    {
        $minutes = floor($sec / $a_min);
        $text = $minutes . $this->plural($minutes, ' minute');
        $sec = $sec - ($minutes * $a_min);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    if($sec >= $a_sec)
    {
        $seconds = floor($sec / $a_sec);
        $text = $sec . $this->plural($seconds, ' seconde');
        $sec = $sec - ($sec * $a_sec);
        array_push($resultStack, $text);
    }

    $result = $resultStack[0];
    for($i = 1; $i <= $detailLevel - 1; $i++)
    {
        if(!empty($resultStack[$i]))
        {
            $result .= $delimiter . $resultStack[$i];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I also added a very simple plural function to return the time unit in a correct grammatical fashion:

```
public function plural($value, $unit)
{
    if($value > 1)
    {
        return $unit . 's';
    }
    else
    {
        return $unit;
    }
}
```

I am not really happy with the for loop, but it actually works fine.

Anyway, thank you very much for your help!